# Why i can't add my tree an element without returnnig the pointer of root?

Tags: c, pointers, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

here's my code , i don't understand the way of these pointers and & works in here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct node {
  int x;
  struct node * left;
  struct node * right;

} node;
void add_Element(node **,int);
node * getNewNode();

void main(){
  node * root = NULL;
  add_Element(&root,4687);
  inorder_tra_recursive(root);
  if(root == NULL) printf("still Nulll\n");
  else printf("not null , working\n");
}

node * getNewNode(){
  node * newNode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
  newNode->left = NULL;
  newNode->right = NULL;
  newNode->x = 0;
  return newNode;
}

void add_Element(node ** root,int data){
  *root = getNewNode();
  (*root)->x = data;
  // I did not  write all function !! this is just a prototype and this is working
}

void inorder_tra_recursive(node * root){// looking for elements to print !
  if(root==NULL) 
     return ;

  inorder_tra_recursive(root->left);
  printf("----%d----\n", root->x);
  inorder_tra_recursive(root->right);
}
```

This is my code and here's the thing that i don't understand when i change my add_Element function to this.

```
void add_Element(node * root,int data){
    if(root==NULL){
        root = getNewNode();
        root->x = data;
    }else{
        if(root->x <= data)
            add_Element(root->right,data);
        else
            add_Element(root->left,data);
    }
}
```

It doesn't add element to the tree . but if i do it like this

node * add_Element(node * root,int data){

```
if(root==NULL){
    root = getNewNode();
    root->x = data;
    return root;
}else{
    if(root->x <= data)
        root->right = add_Element(root->right,data);
    else
        root->right = add_Element(root->left,data);
}
return root;
```

}

It works but what's the difference here why i have to return root to get results.

```
void main(){
   node * root = NULL;
   root = add_Element(root,48464);//random number 
}
```

i can use it like this last one but i have to learn what causing this difference .
(**difference: &root to node ** root // not have to return root , works !
  root to node * root // have to return root otherwise not working**) 
Until this day i thought this 2 way were the same but apparently it's not . So , please help me , i'm going crazy over here :D . Anyhelp will be appreciated , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you mean this?

```
void add_Element(node ** root,int data){
    if(*root==NULL){
        *root = getNewNode();
        (*root)->x = data;
    }else{
        if((*root)->x <= data)
            add_Element(&(*root)->right,data);
        else
            add_Element(&(*root)->left,data);
    }
}
```

In your first example, you are passing a pointer variable by reference (passing `&root` to the `node ** root` parameter).  In the second, you are not (passing only the pointer value `root`, so the pointer variable `root` itself cannot be changed), so the new node object is lost - unless you return it, like you ended up having to do.

Comment: i'm new at this site so i thing i answered my ques. :D if you can comment  it , i'll appreciate it so much , thank you

Answer (score 0):

oh well , i always thought it was like this ,for exp:
    #include

```
void main(){
    int Arr[50];
    random(Arr,50);
    printf("%d", Arr[25]);
```

}

```
void random(int * Arr,int size){
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<size;i++)
   Arr[i] = i+1;
```

}
** so here i'm passing a pointer by reference but when when it's a pointer what i'm passing , i have to use "&" to pass it by reference .
i believe my exp was correct , if it's not there's still  some part that i'm missing**

Comment: Well in this example, you ALREADY created the instance on the `int Arr[50];` line.  You are then passing it as a reference (the array object, not the variable `Arr`) in order to modify its contents.  In your `add_Element()` function you were creating the node INSIDE the function, and it was "stuck" there, until it was returned back somehow.  If you create the root node FIRST, then passed it in, you could modify its contents (like you are doing with the array) - which is another approach as well (so you don't have to pass a variable by reference).

Comment: thanks you so much , mate . i have a exam like 7 hours later and this helped me big time :D first year in collage :D